# Pelican error when generate page 404

Tags: pelican

I have created a file 404.md using the instructions from http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/tips.html

This file contains

`Title: Not Found
Status: hidden
Save_as: 404.html
Date: 2016-01-01 00:00:00`

page 404

When I make ***pelican content***, receive an error

`ERROR: Unknown status 'hidden' for file blog/404.md, skipping it.`

Please advise me, why you can not generate the page. Why does not know the status 'hidden' ?

Thx WalkR

OS: FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE
Pelican: 3.6.3
Python: 2.7.12

Comment: Where is this file located in your source content hierarchy? (full filesystem path, please)

Comment: File are in a directory */home/WalkR/www/www.test.local/content/blog/404.md*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are creating a Page and not an Article. Try removing the `Date:` line in your header, and then move the file to: `/home/WalkR/www/www.test.local/content/pages/404.md`

I have clarified this in the [development version of the docs](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/tips.html#custom-404-pages).

Comment: I'm sorry, I erroneously read the man pages :(
3-4 row ... create a custom 404 page (not an article), such as this Markdown-formatted example stored in content/pages/404.md

Thank you very much Justin